# When induction can be used for infinite sets?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

For example:
Can induction be used for infinite sets for De Morgan's law?

I want to know the necessary conditions.

Comment: It has to be indexed by $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in [Infinite induction "valid"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94513), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction is relevant. Induction works on well-ordered infinite sets.

As far as De Morgan's Laws go, I'm not sure you need induction at all (nor am I sure of a way to apply induction to prove De Morgan's Laws). For example, let $\mathscr A$ be an infinite collection of subsets of some set $X$. Then $\bigcap \mathscr A = \{ x \in X : (\forall A \in \mathscr A)(x \in A) \}$. Then, the complement of $\bigcap \mathscr A$ is the set of $x \in X$ so that $\neg (\forall A \in \mathscr A)(x \in A)$ where $\neg$ is negation, or not. But $\neg (\forall A \in \mathscr A)(x \in A) \equiv (\exists A \in \mathscr A)(x \not\in A)$ where $\equiv$ is logical equivalence. So $$X \setminus \bigcap \mathscr A = \bigcup_{A \in \mathscr A} (X \setminus A).$$